# Customize Biblatex: Delete space before first author

Tags: biblatex

How can I **remove the marked space before the first author** in my bibliography with any entry except for my self-made entry dinvdi (first entry) where there already is no space? Is this by default or did I add some code accidentially which causes this space?

[image]

This is my code:

```
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
%
%
% Preamble
%
%
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

%Definition des Dokumentes
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

%Seitenlayout
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry} %showframe

%Deutsche Umlaute, Englisch, griechische Symbole
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}



% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Literaturverzeichnis und Zitationen
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

%Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage[style           = alphabetic-verb,
            backend         = biber,
            maxbibnames     = 2,
            minbibnames     = 2,
            maxalphanames   = 1,
            minalphanames   = 1,
            useeditor       = false,
            giveninits      = true
            ]{biblatex}

%Name, V.
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} 

%Doppelpunkt nach letztem Verfasser
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\addspace} 

%Änderungen von Strings
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
                andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}, %et al.
                urlseen   = {Abruf\addcolon}, %Anpassung in "Abruf:" bei URLs
                references   = {Literaturverzeichnis},
                bibliography = {Literaturverzeichnis},
                }

%Kapitälchen Nachame und Vorname von Autoren in Bibliografie und in Zitationen
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\ifmknamesc{\textsc{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\ifmknamesc{\textsc{#1}}{#1}}
\def\ifmknamesc{ \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcurrentname{author}} } }
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\textsc{#1}}

%Komma bei mehreren Quellen in Zitation
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

%Semikolon bei mehreren Autoren
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon}%
}

%Formatierung von Regular Database Entry Types
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{\textit{#1\isdot}}

%Formatierung von Zitation bei mehreren Autoren
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

%Formatierung von DIN/ VDI Entries
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate[dinvdi]{\labelelement{\field{note}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{dinvdi}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \printlist{location}
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}
  \printlist{organization}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \printdate
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [dinvdi]
  {booktitleaddon}{\textsc{#1}}


\addbibresource{Literaturverzeichnis_Masterarbeit_CN.bib} % Dateiname anpassen!

\usepackage{citeall} %Zum Testen von Literaturverzeichnis: \citeall


% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Abstände und Platzierungen
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

%Formatierung Inhaltsverzeichnis
\usepackage[notindex, nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{2em}
\dottedcontents{chapter}[21pt]{\addvspace{15pt plus .2pt}\bfseries}{20pt}{9.5pt}
\dottedcontents{section}[50pt]{\addvspace{3pt plus .2pt}}{2.3em}{9.5pt}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[89pt]{\addvspace{3pt plus .2pt}}{3.2em}{9.5pt}

%add stretchable glue (Overfull-/ & Underfull-\hbox-Warnings)
\usepackage{microtype}
\emergencystretch=1em




% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
%
%
% Anfang von Dokumententext
%
%
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}


% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
%
%
%
%
% Beginn des Inhalts
%
%
%
%
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Einleitung}

\cites{DINEN12976-2}{GRA18}{WER17}


% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Literaturverzeichnis - ACHTUNG: Use Biber (instead of BibTeX)!
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

This is the extract of my biblatex-bibliography:

```
    @Dinvdi{DINEN12976-2,
  booktitleaddon = {Din en 12976-2},
  annote         = {Din En 12976-2},
  note           = {Din 12976},
  title          = {Thermische Solaranlagen und ihre Bauteile - Vorgefertigte Anlagen - Teil 2: Pr{\"u}fverfahren},
  year           = {2017},
  date           = {2017-04},
  organization   = {DIN Deutsches Institut f{\"u}r Normung e. V.},
  location       = {Berlin},
}
@Book{GRA18,
  author    = {Grassi, Walter},
  title     = {Heat Pumps},
  year      = {2018},
  date      = {2018},
  subtitle  = {Fundamentals and Applications},
  series    = {Green Energy and Technology},
  publisher = {Springer Nature},
  location  = {Cham, Schweiz},
  isbn      = {978-3-319-62198-2},
}
@Article{WER17,
  author       = {Werner, Sven},
  title        = {International review of district heating and cooling},
  journal      = {Energy},
  journaltitle = {Energy},
  year         = {2017},
  date         = {2017-04-12},
  pages        = {617-631},
  issue        = {137},
}
```

Comment: Remove the irrelevant spaces from `\ifmknamesc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro

```
\def\ifmknamesc{ \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcurrentname{author}} } }
```

leaves spaces behind.

If changed to

```
\def\ifmknamesc{\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcurrentname{author}}}}
```

the spaces disappear

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This solved my problem.